# How to make pagecontrol with text displaying in each view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

How to make pagecontrol with UILabel on each view for displaying texts? I have scroll view inside viecontroller and a label for displaying text. I need to create as many view for displaying different texts.

Comment: you want to replace the dots of `UIPageControl` with `UILabel`s?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using scrollView you can you use collectionView with paging enable feature .. scrollview take lots of memory where collectionView reuses the cell ..
    Use collection horizontal flow layout and make cell size

// Objective-c

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame), (CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame)));
}

//Swift
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth);
}
```

Thanks